# Reflexive Pronouns & Indirect Statements

Tags: conjunctive, esse

The answer key to North & Hillard, Ex. 235 proposes the following Latin translation of:"...until the king, frightened by the ambassador's boldness, promised to do what the Senate decreed."

> ...donec rex audacia legati perterritus promisit se omnia quae Senatus decerneret facturum.

I have two questions about this proposed translation:

- Normally, I would expect in indirect discourse that there should be an "esse" after the future participle, e.g.: "dixi me venturum **esse**" = "I said that I would come." In the above example, the king promised that he would do what the Senate decreed. **Is it acceptable to omit *esse* after *facturum***?
- Secondly, the answer key uses the imperfect subjunctive *decerneret*, while I used the pluperfect active *decreverat*. **Would both options make grammatical sense?**

Answer (score 3):

Omitting *esse* in future infinitives like *facturum esse* is very common and perfectly acceptable.
In fact, if something doesn't seem to quite make sense syntactically, it is often a good idea to check whether there could be an implicit *est* or *esse* somewhere.

I would consider conjunctive to be slightly more natural.
The decision in this sentence is subordinate to *promisit*, a promise by the king.
When a subordinate clause has someone's point of view — like king's here — the predicate is often in conjunctive.
The king made a promise based on his knowledge of the decision.

If you want to emphasize that the decision was a factual event, the indicative is possible.
But here it is a reason for a personal action, so conjunctive is a better choice.